# Is it possible to have any CAN baudrate?

Tags: can, baudrate

Is it possible to have any CAN baud values? e.g. 507 baud

If not, on what basis is the standard values are derived?

Comment: Up to 1Mbps any baud rate is legal, but all devices must be equally configured.

Comment: Some CAN transceivers have minimum baud rate eg MCP2551 has 16 kb/s minimum due to the way the TXD permanent dominant detection works.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are building your own network, yes. All baud rates are valid provided every single device on the bus is using that particular baud rate.

If your bus has devices which are beyond your control, use only standard baud rates, otherwise you will generate error frames.

Standard baud rates are 125 kbit/s, 250 kbit/s, 500 kbit/s and 1 Mbit/s.

I don't know if there is a standard way to "derive" baud values, but most devices come with these baud rates.

Also, you can implement your own algorithm to detect the baud rate of the bus and then configure your device accordingly. One of the methods is described in section 5.1.15 of the docuemnt *[Introduction to the Controller Area Network (CAN)](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/sloa101a/sloa101a.pdf)*.

Comment: Is there a chance that 2 devices, will still communicate, even if they are configured to different baud rate, for example, 1st configured for 1Mbit/s, while the 2nd is configured for 500kbit/s ?

Comment: @ransh No... Not possible! All the devices on a network should have same baud rate.... It's like asking If one is talking in Russian and other in Greek, will they understand each other? :-)

Comment: Right, I just had some piece of code which seemed to do that, but it is more reasonable that I did not understand that code. Now I know that for sure. Thx.